# Xcode 4.3.1 organizer error

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently I upgrade my `Xcode` to to the latest version, today I'm trying to submit  but unfortunately I can't

Here is what i'm doing in the organizer: clicking on `validate button`--> I got the "`log in to itunes account`" box --> I type my Apple ID and password the click on `Next` but nothing happen

I got the same issues while try to `submit the application`

note: tried to restart the `Xcode` and the `iMac`, but the issue persist

[image: i can't pass this step]

i can't pass this step,

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your Xcode schemes to ensure *release* is being used for Archiving?

Comment: yes, i did. also i tried to verify other projects, but i can't log in to itunes connect, (same problem)

Comment: Have you tried logging into iTunes Connect via the website to verify your credentials?

Comment: yes. my credentials are correct, i didn't get login failure or error in user name and password combination. the next button doesn't do any thing.

Comment: You didn't say if you checked using the website or not.

Comment: sorry yes i checked, and i try to validate the application using different id's (even i tried wrong once)

Comment: I would get onto the Apple Developer Forums and ask there.

Comment: my colleague ask the same question https://discussions.apple.com/message/18098795#18098795

Comment: That isn't the Apple Developer forum: https://devforums.apple.com/index.jspa

Comment: yes you are right, did you post the problem, if yes please share the link...

Comment: No I didn't post the problem I'm afraid.

Comment: is their any problem regarding my question.....

Comment: i removed the Xcode from my machine the i reinstall it ant i works finally